# ¿Como Puedo Habilitar o Deshabilitar Ion-Segment-Button a traves de un Boton en Ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic, angular7, ionic-framework, ionic4

Necesito que al momento de darle en un Botón Nuevo deshabilite los ion-segment-button y que al momento de darle a un botón Guardar los habilite Nuevamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ion-Segment cuenta con una propiedad disabled que puede ser activada o desactivada en función de una variable.

```
<ion-segment [disabled]="isDisable" > </ion-segment>
```

Del lado de tu archivo .ts puedes controlar que la variable isDisable sea verdadera al momento de presionar "Nuevo" y falso cuando se presione "Guardar".
Esto bloqueará el segmento cuando la condición sea verdadera,
si quieres deshabilitar únicamente un ion-segment-button también cuenta con la misma propiedad disabled y habilitarse o deshabilitarse en función a una variable que controlas desde tu archivo .ts

```
//Archivo HTML

<ion-segment-button [disabled]="isDisable" (click)="changeButtonState()"> </ion-segment-button>

//Archivo .ts

isDisable = false
changeButtonState(){
this.isDisable  = !this.isDisable
}
```

[Documentación ION SEGMENT Ionic 4](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v4/api/segment)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Fue de Mucha ayuda tu respuesta